# Can't boot Ubuntu partition after replacing the motherboard

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, busybox

Computer specs: 
Model: Dell XPS15 9550
Processor: Intel i7-6700HQ
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M
RAM: 16GB
Storage: 1TB SSD
Dual boot Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10

After replacing the motherboard of the computer, the BIOS configuration was set to default and the Ubuntu partition was undetected. Windows partition remained intact and healthy. Following I made these changes to the BIOS in order to reestablish the partition: 
-Disabled Secure Boot.
-In Boot List Option (set to UEFI), added a Boot Option **Ubuntu** with Filename: **/EFI/ubunt/shimx64.efi**

With those configurations I got the following error during boot:

```
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_T2.FN04._ON, AE_NOT_F  
acpi PHPOCOB:04: Failed to set initial power state  
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.LPCB.H_EC.EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure,  
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_T2.FN04._ON, AE_NOT_  
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.LPCB.H_EC.EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure,  
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_T2.FN04._ON, AE_NOT_  
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.LPCB.H_EC.EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure,  
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_T2.FN04._ON, AE_NOT_  
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.LPCB.H_EC.EC.ECAV] Namespace lookup failure,  
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_T2.FN04._ON, AE_NOT_  
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e  







PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key  
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key  
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

After that I am prompted to a Busy Box v1.27.2 (ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
(initramfs)

Please advise on how to get my partition back up. From the Windows partition I can see that the partition is "healthy" I also tried by configuring the BIOS SATA Operation" from "RAID On" to "AHCI", but I get a blue error screen instead.

Comment: You need to install AHCI drivers into Windows, then change UEFI to AHCI. New motherboard would have defaults, even more than after an UEFI update. You may need to turn UEFI Secure Boot off. You probably are missing the UEFI entries to boot Ubuntu. Many systems find Windows but nothing else. You can totally reinstall grub, often easier with Boot-Repair advanced options, or use efibootmgr to add Ubuntu entry, your shim entry may be correct, but if Ubuntu kernel not Secure boot version it will not boot. Depends on what your original install was.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @oldfred. I was able to make the AHCI drivers work by enabling secure_boot minimal inside windows, then changing the SATA drivers to AHCI in BIOS, then booting again inside Windows and then removing secure_boot.  After that I booted Ubuntu from a live disk, mounted my Ubuntu partition, chrooted inside it and reinstalled the GRUB. After rebooting, I was able to access my partition.